# I wanted to make a program that exits out of the loop when 'exit' is entered and print goodbye when its symmetrical

Tags: python

```
string = ''
txt = ''
while string != 'exit':
    txt = string[::-1]
    string = input('enter:')
    if txt == string:
        print('goodbye')
        break
```

Since Hello[::-1] == olleH why does it not make sense when  string[::-1] == string and whats a better alternative since it doesnt work

Comment: You set `txt` before you get the new input. Move that line below the input line.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're line `string = input('enter:')` is before you get input, you are actually comparing it to the last iteration of the loop.

If you put it after the input, it will reverse the current input and not the last one.

```
string = ''
txt = ''
while string != 'exit':
    string = input('enter:') # note these two swapped lines
    txt = string[::-1] # the other swapped line
    if txt == string:
        print('goodbye')
        break
```